# Probability of rolling 5 dice 4 times and getting the same number on each of them.

Tags: probability

You have 4 turns to roll any given number(say 1 for this example) on 5 fair six-sided-die. If you roll a 1 on only two die on the first try, you only need to roll the other 3 and you have 3 more tries. What would be the probability of getting all the dice to roll a 1 in 4 tries (don't have to reroll a die once it lands on 1)?

Comment: Hint:  think of what happens to a single die.  What's the probability that it comes up $1$ at least once in $4$ tries?

Comment: @lulu I understand the probability of getting 1 if rolling one die once, and the probability of getting the same number if rolling multiple dies at once, but am unsure of how the probability for this scenario would be calculated.

Comment: Just follow my hint, it's practically a full solution.  What's the probability that a single die will come up $1$ at least once in $4$ trials?  Further hint:  the complementary event is "the die comes up something other than $1$ four times in a row."